# Key of JSON Object as from function parameter

Tags: json, typescript, string, function

I know this question was already here, but I do not know how to use it in my case.

I have a function which returns a stringified JSON but I need to change one key with a parameter of this function. I tried something like this to replace it with the value:

```
function toJSON(... name: string, timestamp: number, x :number, y: number ...): string {
    return JSON.stringify({

         ...

        `${name}`: [
          {
            timestamp: timestamp,
            x: x,
            y: y
          }
        ]
        
        ...

    })
```

Is there an easy way to just replace this Key with a parameter?

the `...` means more stuff before and after

Comment: Given that `...` is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in Javascript, it might not be the best idea to use the same sequence in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost good, you should use computed property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015 instead of string template:

```
function toJSON(... name: string, timestamp: number, x:number, y: number ...): string {
  return JSON.stringify({
    ...,
    [name]: [{ timestamp, x, y }]
  });
};
```

Since es2015, you can use shorthand property names, so you can write `{ timestamp, x, y }` instead of redundand: `{ timestamp: timestamp, x: x, y: y }`

Comment: thanks for the tip with ES2015, it cuts my code in fourth